# Problems to generate a unique json using python

Tags: python, json, psycopg2

After several try and research I have been trying how to solve the issue of the error memory by using cur.itersize but still having problems as it not generating what I'm expecting a unique json file with all the rows, what I'm getting is that is generating the same file once after other, not sure how to do it to make the chunks being  appended within a unique json file.
I have tried to run it in a unique query without

```
for row in cur:
```

and and changing fetchmany() and for fetchall() but the table querying is huge and pop errors of out of memory in PostgreSQL, I need the whole dataset.

```
for y in x:
    cur = connection.cursor('test')
    cur.itersize = 2000
    cur.execute(
        " SELECT * FROM table "
    print("fetching data for " + y)
    for row in cur:
        rows = cur.fetchmany(2000)
        print("Generating json")
        rowarray_list = []
        print("parsing rows to json file")
        json_data = json.dumps(rows)
        filename = '%s.json' % y
        print('File: ' + filename + ' created')
        with open(filename, "w") as f:
            f.write(json_data)
```

Comment: in `for row` loop you always open file with the same name and in write mode - so you remove previous content and writ only new content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some things you could do to solve the memory problem, and bugs, and also increase performance.

- limit the result in the query using limit/offset and use `fetchall` instead of using `fetchmany`. i.e. "SELECT * FROM table **LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0**";
- set the mode in `open` to "a" (append) instead of "w" (write);

my suggested code:

```
limit = 10

for y in x:
    print("fetching data for " + y)
    filename = '%s.json' % y

    page = 0

    while 1:
        offset = limit * page

        with connection.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT %s OFFSET %s", (limit, offset))
            rows = cur.fetchall()

        if not rows:
            break

        with open(filename, "a") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(rows))

        page += 1
```

Comment: thanks i will try your option, this will work for the large dataset is querying and why the reason of the memory issue? also limit 10 is for any reason, i am querying around 50 million records so 10 by 10  could be tedious

Comment: this will query fewer data which is much better. regarding the limit, you could use a larger number to fit your needs, just by changing the value of `limit`.

Comment: and is not duplicating data within the process, the json generated is bigger than expected. Thanks!

Comment: @jr.gcj consider marking the post as a correct answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: it is still processing. As soon is ok not doubts I will post correct your answer, as you are asking, jsut asking if you know if this method generate huge json and if you know better way to optimize the size of the json generated. Thanks

Comment: instead of creating only one file for each `y`, you could split it into more files using some sort of category that your tabla may have. e.g. "y".json to "y".categoryX.json, "y".categoryY.json, "y".categoryZ.json.

Comment: is not doing the job correctly when finishing  it pop this error: Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: this error has nothing with this code. probably you are passing the wrong parameter's type to PostgreSQL such as int instead of a string.